# Unable to save address after data migration

Tags: magento2

One or more input exceptions have occurred.
"postcode" is required. Enter and try again.
"countryId" is required. Enter and try again.

I'm filling these values in my account edit address page, but facing this issue.

https://prnt.sc/u95nez

Comment: https://prnt.sc/u95rnd

Comment: https://prnt.sc/u95s2g

Answer (score 0):

During migration, there is a problem with the loss `postcode` and `telephone` attributes values from `customer_form_attribute` and `eav_form_element` tables.

Adding missing values might help:

```sql
INSERT INTO customer_form_attribute (form_code, attribute_id)
VALUES ('adminhtml_customer_address', '33'),
       ('customer_address_edit', '33'),
       ('customer_register_address', '33'),
       ('adminhtml_customer_address', '34'),
       ('customer_address_edit', '34'),
       ('customer_register_address', '34');


INSERT INTO eav_form_element (element_id, type_id, fieldset_id, attribute_id, sort_order)
VALUES (NULL, '1', NULL, '33', '7'),
       (NULL, '2', NULL, '33', '7'),
       (NULL, '3', NULL, '33', '6'),
       (NULL, '4', NULL, '33', '6'),
       (NULL, '1', NULL, '34', '9'),
       (NULL, '2', NULL, '34', '9'),
       (NULL, '3', NULL, '34', '8'),
       (NULL, '4', NULL, '34', '8');
```